# Network Printing Requires Authentication

Tags: 11.10, windows, printing, networking, password

I am trying to print a PDF on an Ubuntu, and the printer is hooked up to my Windows desktop. Everything is going fine, but when I test-print a page, it asks me for authentication. The default username is `francislau` and there is a blank password box. I tried my Ubuntu password but it was incorrect. Does anyone know what the credientials are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Francis, I encountered exactly the same issue.

When I use the Windows username and password, the document prints successfully, but it is a nuisance because I must enter the user/pass for every document that I print.

I solved the issue after finding [this bug report](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg2426437.html). In summary, delete your printer and add it again, but make sure you use the correct user/pass combination *the very first time* you are prompted for it.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

If the Windows computer is responsible for the printer share, I would suggest diagnosing password issues from the Windows side. Depending on your Windows OS version, you can try googling for "windows  print share password". I see a couple good forums on this topic on tomshardware.com when I do this search.

Comment: Thanks nathwill, I will take a look at the diagnostics at my Windows computer.